# Error when displaying tasks from mpp file to extjs tree grid in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, extjs6

```
Extjs code:

Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled:true
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'Importtool',
    launch: function () {

        Ext.define('Task', {
            extend: Ext.data.Model,
            fields: [
                { name: 'task', type: 'string' },
                {name:'id' ,type:'string'},
                { name: 'uniqueid', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'parentid', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'startdate', type: 'string' },
                {name:'enddate',type:'string'}
            ]
        });
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
            model: 'Task',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'mpp.aspx/GetData'

            },

        });

        Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
            title: 'Tree Grid',
            width: 1300,
            height: 450,
            store: store,
            rootVisible: false,
            useArrows: true,
            lines: false,
            scope: this,
            renderTo: 'tree-view',
            columns: [{
                xtype: 'treecolumn',
                text: 'Task',
                flex: 1,
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'task'
            }, {
                text: 'Id',
                sortable: true,
                width: 150,
                dataIndex: 'id'
            }, {
                text: 'Unique Id',
                width: 150,
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'uniqueid'
            },
            {
                text: 'Parent ID',
                width: 150,
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'parentid'
            },
            {
                text: 'Start Date',
                width: 150,
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'startdate'
            },
            {
                text: 'End Date',
                width: 150,
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'enddate'
            }],
        });
    }
});

Asp.net code:

public void GetTasks()
        {
            System.Collections.Generic.List<Tasks> lstTasks = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Tasks>();
            foreach (Task task in ToEnumerable(projectObj.getAllTasks())) //Gets all tasks from mpp file
            {

                lstTasks.Add(new Tasks
                {
                    TaskName = task.getName(),
                    TaskId = Convert.ToString(task.getID()),
                    TaskUniqueId = Convert.ToString(task.getUniqueID()),
                    //Level = Convert.ToString(task.getOutlineLevel()).Trim(),
                    //OutLine = Convert.ToString(task.getOutlineNumber())
                    TaskParentId = Convert.ToString(task.getOutlineLevel()),
                    StartDate = Convert.ToString(task.getStart()),
                    EndDate=Convert.ToString(task.getFinish()),

                    TaskCompletePercent=Convert.ToString(task.getPercentageComplete())
                });


               // rpt_tasks.DataSource = lstTasks;
               // rpt_tasks.DataBind();
            }
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstTasks);
            Response.Write(json);

        }
```

Issue is that when i run this code Unable to parse JSON warning occurs.So i am not understanding what really the issue is. I am new new to Ext Js. I want to display mpp file data in extjs tree grid. I am being searching for references on web for last couple of days and not a single example is there so i am very desperate to solve this issue. Please guide me through this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ext.Ajax.request to call the service and in success method of ajax decode the json returned from service.

```
var objData={};
var b=Ext.encode(objData);
Ext.Ajax.request({
 url:service url,
 jsonData:{b},
success:function(response){
var data=Ext.decode(response.responseText);
var mystore=Ext.getStore(storename);
mystore.loadRawData(data);
}
});
```

And then bind this store to tree grid.